# stack overflow error in delphi

Tags: delphi, stack-overflow

I have a procedure which calls several functions:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rawData: TRawData;
  rawInts: TRawInts;
  processedData: TProcessedData;
begin
  rawData := getRawData();
  rawInts := getRawInts(rawData);
  processedData := getProcessedData(rawInts);
end;
```

The data types are defined like this:

```
TRawData = array[0..131069] of Byte;
TRawInts = array[0..65534] of LongInt;
TProcessedData = array[0..65534] of Double;
```

running the program with just:

```
rawData := getRawData();
rawInts := getRawInts(rawData);
```

Works totally fine. However, when I try to run:

```
getProcessedData(rawInts)
```

I get a stackoverflow error. I don't see why this is. The function code for `getProcessedData` is very simple:

```
function getProcessedData(rawInts : TRawInts) : TProcessedData;
var
  i: Integer;
  tempData: TProcessedData;
  scaleFactor: Double;
begin
  scaleFactor := 0.01;

  for i := 0 to 65534 do
    tempData[i] := rawInts[i] * scaleFactor;

  Result := tempData;
end;
```

Why is this causing an error ?

Comment: When taking the code out of the getProcessedData function and putting it manually in the procedure this error still occurs. In addition to this, the error seem to be thrown when entering getRawData ... I have no clue why this is.

Comment: Local variables are allocated on the stack, and presumably, `array[0..65534] of double;` is too big, causing a stack overflow.

Comment: Ok, I'll shorten the array and see if that works.

Comment: You are correct. That's a bit of a problem really, as I really need the array of doubles to be that long. Can I extend the length of the stack in some way? (That might be a really stupid question..)

Comment: Can I use a global variable to save space on the stack because I am not creating the large dataset inside the function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default maximum stack size for a thread is 1 MB. The three local variables of `Button1Click` total 131,070 + 65,535 * 4 + 65,535 * 8 = 917,490 bytes. When you call `getProcessedData`, you pass the parameter by value, which means that the function makes a local copy of the parameter on the stack. That adds `SizeOf(TRawInts)` = 262,140 bytes to bring the stack to at least 1,179,630 bytes, or about 1.1 MB. There's your stack overflow.

You can reduce the stack use by passing the `TRawInts` array by reference instead. Then the function won't make its own copy. [Zdravko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22698003/33732) suggests using `var`, but since the function has no need to modify the passed-in array, you should use `const` instead.

```
function getProcessedData(const rawInts: TRawInts): TProcessedData;
```

Naively, we might expect the `tempData` and `Result` variables in `getProcessedData` to occupy additional stack space, but in reality, they probably won't. First, large return types typically result in the compiler changing the function signature, so it would act more like your function were declared with a `var` parameter instead of a return value:

```
procedure getProcessedData(rawInts: TRawInts; var Result: TProcessedData);
```

Then the call is transformed accordingly:

```
getProcessedData(rawInts, processedData);
```

Thus, `Result` doesn't take up any more stack space because it's really just an alias for the variable in the caller's frame.

Furthermore, sometimes the compiler recognizes that an assignment at the end of your function, like `Result := tempData`, means that `tempData` doesn't really need any space of its own. Instead, the compiler may treat your function as though you had been writing directly into `Result` all along:

```
begin
  scaleFactor := 0.01;

  for i := 0 to 65534 do
    Result[i] := rawInts[i] * scaleFactor;
end;
```

However, it's best not to *count* on the compiler to make those sorts of memory-saving changes. Instead, it's better not to lean so heavily on the stack in the first place. To do that, you can use *dynamic arrays*. Those will move the large amounts of memory out of the stack and into the *heap*, which is the part of memory used for dynamic allocation. Start by changing the definitions of your array types:

```
type
  TRawData = array of Byte;
  TRawInts = array of Integer;
  TProcessedData = array of Double;
```

Then, in your functions that return those types, use `SetLength` to assign the length of each array. For example, the function we've seen already might go like this:

```
function getProcessedData(const rawInts: TRawInts): TProcessedData;
var
  i: Integer;
  scaleFactor: Double;
begin
  Assert(Length(rawInts) = 65535);
  SetLength(Result, Length(rawInts));

  scaleFactor := 0.01;

  for i := 0 to High(rawInts) do
    Result[i] := rawInts[i] * scaleFactor;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your answer, I have a question, you said that "since the function has no need to modify the passed-in array, you should use const instead." Do you mean in terms of length? because does the multiplication by scaleFactor not modify the array?

Comment: @Tim: No, it modifies the *content* of the array, not the array itself. They're not the same thing. Passing a `const SL: TStringList` does not mean you can't add items to the stringlist; it means you can't free the stringlist itself and create a new instance in that variable.

Comment: No, multiplying two values doesn't modify either of those values. See for yourself: Inspect the contents of `rawInts` before and after you call the function, and you'll see that the values in that array haven't changed. If you were assigning new values into the same array you were reading from, then the array couldn't be const, but in your case, you're assigning the product into an entirely separate array (`tempData` or `Result`).

Comment: That's not what I was referring to, @Ken. When I wrote about using `const` instead of `var`, there were no reference types involved. Delphi doesn't allow any of the elements of a const static-array parameter to be modified, does it?

Comment: I see, I was being stupid, its not rawInts which is modified at all, only result. I get this now, I'll change my code. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @RobKennedy Thank so much for your support, I followed your instructions and its all working fine and dandy now. Massive Respect.

Comment: @RobKennedy: one small detail you omitted - there are separate **Minimum** and **Maximum** stack sizes, where the default **Minimum** is 16K and the default **Maximum** is 1MB. So a thread starts with an initial stack size of 16K and grows its stack dynamically as needed until it exceeds 1MB, at which point it then raises the overflow error.

Answer (score 2):

These objects are all very large. And you appear to be allocating them as local variables. They will reside on the stack which has an fixed size, by default 1MB on Windows. You have allocated enough of these large objects in various parts of the call stack to exceed the 1MB limit. Hence a stack overflow.

Another problem in your code is the way you pass these objects as parameters. Passing large objects as value parameters results in copies being made. Copying an integer or two is nothing to worry about. Copying 65 thousand doubles is wasteful. It hurts performance. Don't do that. Pass references to large objects. Passing as `const` parameters achieves that.

The stack is well suited for small objects. It is not suited to these large objects. Allocate these objects on the heap. Use dynamic arrays: `array of Integer`, `TArray<Integer>` etc.

Do not increase the default stack size for your process. Especially in modern times of multi-core machines this is a recipe for out of memory errors.

Do not use magic constants. Use `low()` and `high()` to obtain array bounds.

Do pass input parameters by `const`. This allows the compiler to make optimisations that are significantly beneficial.

Comment: So I declare my arrays, within the procedure, using dynamic arrays, then how do I pass these to the functions? myFunc(const myArray : array of double) ??

Comment: That's right. That's an open array which is good. Declare as dynamic array for the actual variables. `TArray<T>` if you use modern Delphi.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your patience, I come from an electronics background and this is my first real time coding using large data sets, I can see I don't have enough appreciation for the limits of a PC, I keep seeing it as an infinite resource.

Comment: All I can say is don't do anything that Zdravko advised. And read Rob's excellent answer carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The key issue here is the size of your arrays.

If you use `SizeOf` you will see that they are probably larger than you think:

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TRawData = array[0..131069] of Byte;
  TRawInts = array[0..65534] of Longint;
  TProcessedData = array[0..65534] of Double;
begin
  try
    writeln('TProcessedData:':20, SizeOf(TProcessedData):8);
    writeln('TRawData:':20, SizeOf(TRawData):8);
    writeln('TRawInts:':20, SizeOf(TRawInts):8);
    writeln('Total:':20, SizeOf(TRawInts) + SizeOf(TProcessedData) + SizeOf(TRawData):8);

    readln;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Output:

> ```
>  TProcessedData:  524280
>        TRawData:  131070
>        TRawInts:  262140
>           Total:  917490
> ```

So most of the 1MB stack is consumed by the arrays. As some of the stack will already be allocated, you get a stack overflow.

This can be avoid by using dynamic arrays, which have their memory allocated from the *heap*.

```
TRawData = array of Byte;
TRawInts = array of Longint;
TProcessedData = array of Double;

...
SetLength(TProcessedData, 65535); 
...
```